# Rewrite rule (page doens't have get values)

Tags: apache, url, include, url-rewriting

Dear Stackoverflowers,

I was trying out the rewrite function and so I've read some on the internet on how it works.
Apparently, i can't figure it out, so i decided to use this http://www.generateit.net/mod-rewrite/ web application to write one for me. But if i use it now, i shows my page but not with the working stylesheets, $_GET values and includes.

My original link: http://web.awitgoed.nl/artikelen.php?c=stofzuigers

The one i want it to be: http://web.awitgoed.nl/artikelen/stofzuigers.html

And here is the code i got from the generator:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^artikelen/([^/]*)\.html$ /artikelen.php?c=$1 [L]
```

I guess the problem is the slash at the end of 'artikelen' because it thinks its a sub directory or something? The file 'artikelen.php' is in the root directory.

Thanks in advance,
Délano

---

Update: so i decided to give it a go on my localhost and thanks to Matthew the visuals are working fine now, but still the paremeters ($_GET) are not getting through. Is there any server side settings that are needed to be changed in order to get this working?

Comment: What happens if you do a print_r($_GET) on the page, do you get anything?

Answer (score 0):

You need to added leading slashes to your page so that it starts from the root, so

```
<script src="javascript/jquery.js"></script>
```

Would become

```
<script src="/javascript/jquery.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks, that seems to solve at least the visual problems. But still i don't get my $_GET['c'] value. Which is the part behind artikelen/$_GET['C']value.

Comment: Yes, yes i am. Also, the complete var_dump of the get variable is empty.

Comment: Your page must be redirecting or the get getting reset somewhere then.